# GLES30 Ray Picking gluUnProject

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0, ray-picking

I worked through lot of tutorials and finally created a nice cube simulator.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot2]

Now I want to implement ray picking.
For this I created a simple GL_LINE_STRIP to visualize my ray.
Unfortunately when I check near and far point values they make no sense or I interprete them wrong.
I would expect near point close to camera origin, but it is close to 0, therefore my ray starts in the middle of my scene.
[image: Projectionmatrix]

Projectionmatrix:

```
Matrix.perspectiveM(projectionmatrix, 0, 20.0f, (float) mWidth / (float) mHeight, 0.1f, 300.0f);
```

ViewMatrix:

```
camX = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(phi)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(counter)) * radius);
camY = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(phi)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(counter)) * radius);
camZ = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(phi)) * radius;
Matrix.setLookAtM(ViewMatrix, 0, camX, camY, camZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Ray Pick:

```
float winx = xTouch, winy =(float)viewport[3] - yTouch;
int result = GLU.gluUnProject(winx, winy, 1.0f, ViewMatrix, 0, projectionmatrix, 0, viewport, 0, temp, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMV(temp2, 0, ViewMatrix, 0, temp, 0);
if(result == GL10.GL_TRUE){
    near[0] = temp2[0] / temp2[3];
    near[1] = temp2[1] / temp2[3];
    near[2] = temp2[2] / temp2[3];
}
    
result = GLU.gluUnProject(winx, winy, 0.0f, ViewMatrix, 0, projectionmatrix, 0, viewport, 0, temp3, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMV(temp2,0,ViewMatrix, 0, temp3, 0);
if(result == GL10.GL_TRUE){
    far[0] = temp2[0] / temp2[3];
    far[1] = temp2[1] / temp2[3];
    far[2] = temp2[2] / temp2[3];
}
P0 = near;
P1 = far;

float lineVerticesData[] =
                {
                        // positions          // colors           // texture 
                        0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 
                };
      lineVerticesData[0] = P0[0];
      lineVerticesData[1] = P0[1];
      lineVerticesData[2] = P0[2];
      lineVerticesData[9] = P1[0];
      lineVerticesData[10] = P1[1];
      lineVerticesData[11] = P1[2];

        VBO_BindBufferFloat(VBOIds[3],Float_to_FloatBuffer(lineVerticesData),lineVerticesData.length);
        VAO_BindBuffer(VAOId[2],VBOIds[3],0);
```

Log: lineVerticsData: [8.532211, 49.11434, -50.042286, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0054870476, -0.0148345595, -0.09998755, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0

I also followed the solution from here, but I was not able to get a proper ray:
https://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html

```
        int[] viewport = {0, 0, width, height};
        float x = (2.0f * xTouch) / width - 1.0f;
        float y = 1.0f - (2.0f * yTouch) / height;
     
        Matrix.setIdentityM(inverseview,0);
        Matrix.invertM(inverseview,0,ViewMatrix,0);
        Matrix.invertM(inverseproj,0, projectionmatrix,0);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(initcoords,0);
        Matrix.translateM(initcoords,0,x,y,0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(helpm,0, inverseproj,0,initcoards,0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(tmodelmatrix,0, inverseview,0,helpm,0);

    private static float DefaultShapeVertices[] =
                    {
                            // positions          // colors           // texture coords
                           0.0f,  0.0f, -100.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, 
                            0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, }
    Shaderprog1.setMat4("model", tmodelmatrix);
```